# Raspberry pi USB webcam problem

Tags: usb, camera

When I try to take an image through the fswebcam, Raspberry Pi 2 shows following error.

```
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Error selecting input 0
VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy
```

And I am using following command to take the photo:

`fswebcam image.jpg`

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to RPi.SE. The last line in your error suggests that your device file is being used somewhere else. (could be abruptly closed application or improper programming)   You can unplug it and try plugging it back to see if it makes any difference. You can explore detailed `fswebcam` options from this link : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fswebcam.1.html

Comment: I tried it couple of times, that didn't work

Comment: Your problem seems to be very similar to one mentioned over here. https://93.93.130.214/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=104330&p=724054. Are you sure there is no other process using the camera ?

Comment: I found that, motion which i have installed is creating this problem. I uninstalled it, then it was working fine.

Comment: The same service that was causing the problem in that thread I believe. :) Glad that you solved it. You can add your findings as an answer so that it can help others having the same problem.

Comment: If we install and run the "lsof" command ... for example `sudo lsof /dev/video0` ... I am wondering out loud if this would not show who else has the file open?

Comment: how much time before it fails? can you force it to fail? or is it failed simply when you go to use it? can you post dmesg output from the time when the error occurs? (I suspect you have some sort of power issue on the USB port, which is forcing the device into error.) hopefully dmesg will give us some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall motion

**sudo apt-get remove motion**

(It worked for me after uninstallation)

It may suffice to disable motion (`sudo systemctl disable motion`), as this will release the cam for use with other app.

Comment: Is there a reason why this should be related to the problem?

Comment: There are two packages trying to access the same webcam. So either you can do with fswebcam or with motion. So when there is only one of them, the webcam won't be showing any resource busy error.

Answer (score -1):

For others who may have this problem, try unplugging and then plugging the webcam again. See if it works then.